# Integration seems to be taking infinite time, cannot integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

This double integral seems to take infinite time as it has been running for hours now. How can this double integral be solved?

`J*Integrate[Integrate[Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]/L]], {a, -a, a}], {b, -b,b}, Assumptions -> {Element[b, Reals]}]`

Comment: You integrate with `{a, -a, a}` ?  compare `Integrate[Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]/L]], a]` with `Integrate[Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]/L]], {a,-a,a}]`

Comment: I want the integral to integrate from `-a` to `a`. Is this not possible?

Comment: The `{a,-a,a}` is causing Mathematica some trouble. So this is a workaround

Comment: So you suggest doing the integration as mentioned above, and then calculating the limit separately?

Comment: A simple clarifying question, please: ignoring the limits on the integral, are you trying to integrate with respect to the variables x and y or with respect to a and b?

Comment: I am trying to integrate with respect to a and b

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So the nomenclature {a, -a, a} is odd to me. Does Mathematica consider the first a, the integration variable, local and the integration limits (the -a and second a) are separate symbols?

Comment: This seems to work better although it is by no means fast. `Integrate[ Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]/ll]], {a, -a0, a0}, {b
, -b0, b0}, Assumptions -> {Element[{x, y, ll}, Reals], x > a0 > 0, y > b0 > 0}]`. Notice that I made some assumptions on parameters that might or might not be what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`TrigToExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html) to simplify the integrand prior to integrating.

```
(int = Assuming[{Element[{x, y}, Reals], a > 0, b > 0, L > 0},
    J*Integrate[
      Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]/L]] //
        TrigToExp // FullSimplify,
      {x0, -a, a}, {y0, -b, b}]]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {82.7213, 
 J L (L ArcTan[((-a + x) (b - y))/(
      L Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2])] - 
    L ArcTan[((a + x) (b - y))/(
      L Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2])] + 
    L ArcTan[((-a + x) (b + y))/(
      L Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2])] - 
    L ArcTan[((a + x) (b + y))/(
      L Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2])] - 
    b Log[-a + x + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] + 
    y Log[-a + x + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] - 
    a Log[-b + y + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] + 
    x Log[-b + y + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] + 
    b Log[a + x + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] -
     y Log[a + x + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] - 
    a Log[-b + y + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] - 
    x Log[-b + y + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 - 2 b y + y^2]] - 
    b Log[-a + x + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]] - 
    y Log[-a + x + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]] + 
    a Log[b + y + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]] -
     x Log[b + y + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 - 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]] + 
    b Log[a + x + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]] +
     y Log[a + x + Sqrt[
       a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]] + 
    a Log[b + y + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]] +
     x Log[b + y + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + L^2 + 2 a x + x^2 + 2 b y + y^2]])} *)
```

Simplifying under the same assumptions

```
int2 = Assuming[{Element[{x, y}, Reals], a > 0, b > 0, L > 0},
  int // FullSimplify]

(* J L (-L (ArcTan[((a - x) (b - y))/(
       L Sqrt[L^2 + (a - x)^2 + (b - y)^2])] + 
      ArcTan[((a + x) (b - y))/(
       L Sqrt[L^2 + (a + x)^2 + (b - y)^2])] + 
      ArcTan[((a - x) (b + y))/(
       L Sqrt[L^2 + (a - x)^2 + (b + y)^2])] + 
      ArcTan[((a + x) (b + y))/(
       L Sqrt[L^2 + (a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2])]) + (-b + y) Log[-a + x + 
      Sqrt[L^2 + (a - x)^2 + (b - y)^2]] + (b - y) Log[
     a + x + Sqrt[L^2 + (a + x)^2 + (b - y)^2]] + (-a + x) Log[-b + 
      Sqrt[L^2 + (a - x)^2 + (b - y)^2] + y] - (a + x) Log[-b + Sqrt[
      L^2 + (a + x)^2 + (b - y)^2] + y] + (a - x) Log[
     b + y + Sqrt[L^2 + (a - x)^2 + (b + y)^2]] - (b + 
      y) (Log[-a + x + Sqrt[L^2 + (a - x)^2 + (b + y)^2]] - 
      Log[a + x + Sqrt[L^2 + (a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2]]) + (a + x) Log[
     b + y + Sqrt[L^2 + (a + x)^2 + (b + y)^2]]) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{a,-a,a}` is causing Mathematica some trouble. I find it strange notation myself. Normally the limits of integration are definite values or some other parameters different from the integration variable itself. At least at school this is what our calculus teacher told us. I do not think I've seen a problem saying `Integrate[f[x],{x,-x,x}]` before.

But this is a workaround. I can't verify if the final result is correct or not.

`Integrate` as indefinite and then use Limit command to obtain the value at lower limit `-a` then take the difference to find the definite integral.

Do the same for `b`.  Now it works and it does not hang.

```
 ClearAll[a, x, y, b, L]
 int1= Integrate[Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]/L]], a];
 lower = Limit[int1, a -> -a, GenerateConditions -> False];
 int1 = int1 - lower // FullSimplify;
 int2 = Integrate[int1, b];
 int2lower = Limit[int2, b -> -b];
 final = int2 - int2lower // Simplify;
 final = J*final
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note however that [using indefinite integrals to evaluate definite integrals is dangerous in Mathematica](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/), essentially because you might integrate across a branch cut.  In addition, `Integrate[f[x], {x, -x, x}]` looks strange, but Mathematica will scope the integration variable `x` so that internally, it will actually do a calculation like `Integrate[f[y], {y, -x, x}]`.

Comment: Thanks @march. I know that taking the limits like this implies it is proper integral ofcourse. That is why I said  I can't verify if the final result is correct or not. I just assumed it was. I did not know that Mathematica internally does what you said. That is good to know.